# my onClickListener on my recyclerView doesn't get called what can be the reasion

Tags: android

i made a onClickListener for my recyclerView but it just didn't work.
When i click an item from the recyclerView the log doesnt appear, the commands i put in the OnClickListener arent called ,i spend already 2-3 days to find the problem but i didn't see something wrong in my code it should cost the problem, probably its a small stupid mistake 
but pls if anyone can help me get the problem i will be very happy. 
In my adapter class i assigned the onClick to check and uncheck a checkbox 
and in the MainActivity i assigned to save it in the dataBase

this is in my main activity

```
     private void setUpGUI() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylerView);
    adapter = new ItemAdapter(new ItemAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(TodoItem item) {
            Log.d(TAG, "on item click");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(TodoItemsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + item.getId());

            getContentResolver().update(uri, item.toContentValues(), null, null);
        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAddItemPopup();
        }
    });
```

this is my adapter class

```
    public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private static final String TAG = "item adapter";
private List<TodoItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public ItemAdapter(ItemClickListener listener) {
    itemClickListener = listener;
}

public void addItem(TodoItem item) {
    if (!items.contains(item)) {
        items.add(item);
        Collections.sort(items);
        notifyItemInserted(items.indexOf(item));
    }
}

public void addItems(Collection<TodoItem> newItems) {

    for (TodoItem item : newItems) {
        if (!items.contains(item)) {
            items.add(item);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public TodoItem getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    items.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

// This listener listens for clicks to the viewholder. The viewholder passes back the position it is.
private final ClickListener clickListener = new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "on click adapter");
        // Get the item that was clicked
        TodoItem item = items.get(position);


        // Set the completed state
        item.setCompleted(!item.isCompleted());

        //Update the UI
        notifyItemChanged(position);

        // Pass the item back the the itemclicklistener
        itemClickListener.onItemClicked(item);
    }
};


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v, clickListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    TodoItem item = items.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(item.getText());
    holder.subTextViewA.setText(item.getSubText());
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(item.isCompleted());

    //holder.backgroundLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ec48e418"));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}


// The view holder listens to clicks on the
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    // private RelativeLayout backgroundLayout;
    final TextView textView, subTextViewA;
    final CheckBox checkBox;
    final ClickListener clickListener;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, ClickListener clickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        subTextViewA = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subTextViewA);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        //backgroundLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayout);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClicked(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

// Private listener fot the adapter to know about view clicks
private interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(int position);
}

// Public listener to pass the item back to the activity
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(TodoItem item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you click on your checkox, itemView.OnClickListener does not invoke. http://screencast.com/t/moP30Lfc49X

You can set click listener for checkbox and save (or remove) items from database like that http://screencast.com/t/Iw1K3Ld8nna

```
holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onItemClickListener.onItemClick(item, holder.checkBox.isChecked());
    }
});



public interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(MainActivity.Item item, boolean save);

}
```

In your activity:

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Item item, boolean save) {
        if (save) {
            // Save
        } else {
            // Remove from db
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer but i want to set the onClickListener on the whole view because i want to set a popup when i click the view ,,i tried to set it in the ViewHolder with  itemView.setOnClickListener(this);but this line didn't work ,,for the checkBox alone a can make             checkBox.setOnClickListener(this); but thanks anyway

Comment: yes i want to be able to click on the whole view to pop up a dialog,,and the click listener needs to work because of this line             itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
but it didn't work ,,i can make  textView.setOnClickListener(this); but its only on the textView not on the whole view .thanks